# Generate C# Code from *.xsd files for use as WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services, xsd, svcutil.exe, contract-first

**Update**

I want to generate C# classes files to be used as WCF service based on *.xsd files. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

```
svcutil <xsd_file>
```

where `<xsd_file>` is the path to the XSD file. As John Saunders mentioned, read the command-line syntax and available command options using `svcutil /?`. This tool does have a lot of functionality, so read carefully.

Also, remember to use the Windows SDK Command Prompt instead of the standard Command Prompt to execute this tool.

Answer (score 0):

use wcf.blue plugin for visual studio